# Why mongodb stores some numbers as NumberLong?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Mongodb is installed on Windows 8 and I use `spring-data-mongodb` to work with it.
I have collection with field `pId`, it's a number.
I see strange situation, mongodb stores some `pId` as simple number but some of them as `NumberLong`.

query:

```
db.mycollection.distinct("pId", {"dayDate" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2015-04-14T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

output:

```
[ 61885, 61886, NumberLong(61887) ]
```

Why it happens and may I change something to use the same data type for all `pId` values?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Laravel with MongoDB, and as far as my understanding of MongoDB, I founded that:
If you're saving your data (numbers) in quote than, it will save as string, but if you assign number to variable in normal way (no quotes) then it will save in NumberLong format or when you are doing type cast by using **(int)**

> Example.

```
$data = '1' (Stores as string)
$data = 1 or $data = (int)'1' (Store as NumberLong)
```

Comment: `pId` has `Long` type in Java

Comment: In Mongo tools I see `61886` is `Int64` but `61887` is `Int32`

Comment: In above scenario, collection and technique for saving the data is same?

Comment: yep, I have only one method in my app to add records to mongo db.